# Writing a JSON file using multiprocessing - Python

Tags: python, json, multiprocessing

I have a JSON that has some values that must be extracted, processed and with those, add new values to the file. To do this, I use multiprocessing and although it is a priori synchronized I got race conditions.

The function that is called just transforms a rating between a range of 0-5 to a range of 0-100.

Thanks in advance!

```
import json
import multiprocessing

n = 1000

maxRating = 5
percentage = 100

inputfile= 'rawData.JSON'

outfile= 'processedData.JSON'

#load data into dictionary "data"
with open(inputfile) as f:
    data = json.load(f)

#create an empty dictionary that will contain the new informations 
results = {}

def saver(init,end,q,l):
    for num in range(init, end):
        l.acquire()
        rating = data["bars"][num]["rating"]

        ratioRating = (percentage * rating) / maxRating

        results["ratingP"] = ratioRating
        print(ratioRating)
        #put data in queue
        q.put(results)
        l.release()

#main function
if __name__ == '__main__':
    i = 0
    cores = 4

    q = multiprocessing.Queue() 

    lock = multiprocessing.Lock()

    if(cores > 1): #parallel
        for i in range (cores):
            init = (i*n)/cores
            fin = ((i+1)*n)/cores
            p = multiprocessing.Process(target = saver, args = (init,fin,q,lock)).start()

        for i in range (n):
            data["bars"][i].update(q.get()) #update "data" dictionary adding new processed data

    else: #sequential
        saver(0,n,q)
        for l in range (n):
            data["bars"][l].update(q.get()) #update "data" dictionary adding new processed data

    #write the updated JSON file with the added processed data
    with open(outfile,'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(data,outfile)
```

Comment: Can you include the error you are getting?

Comment: @BertKellerman it is a race condition error, the updated value is not corresponding to the one that has been read from the original JSON. I suppose there is a problem with the locking.